# Run AJAX when jQuery UI datetimepicker is closed and date/time is changed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am running AJAX when datetimepicker is closed after selecting a date and time. The issue is found when no date and time is changed and AJAX still runs. I want to run AJAX only when date or time is changed and datetimepicker is closed. If same date and time remains then no AJAX should be called.

Here's is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hidden_datepicker").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
    showButtonPanel: false,
    onClose: function() {
      // To stop time slider from removing the button text when clicking
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax/date-format.php',
          data: 'date=' + $(this).val(),
          success: function(data) {
            $("#btndate").text(data);
            // Hide datepicker
            $("#hidden_customer_progress_date").datetimepicker("hide");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  $("#btndate").click(function() {
    // Check if datepicker is open
    if ($("#hidden_datepicker").datepicker("widget").is(":visible")) {
      $("#hidden_datepicker").datetimepicker("hide");
    } else {
      $("#hidden_datepicker").datetimepicker("show");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#hidden_datepicker {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btndate">Date</button>
<input type="text" id="hidden_datepicker" />
```

Comment: Change `onClose` to `onSelect`. Voting to close as a typographical issue. Also note that the docs for the datepicker are here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: No, I was using `onSelect` previously but its having an issue regarding time slider. The ajax runs when time slider moves. I want to run ajax only when user has selected all date and time just like phpmyadmin date field.

Comment: In which case you need to use `onSelect` and address that issue separately. Also note that your fiddle is broken as you load the scripts in the wrong order and the datetimepicker itself is missing.

Comment: i think phpmyadmin uses `onClose`

Comment: @user5307298 how is phpmyadmin involved in the question?

Comment: because I'm trying to implement datetimepicker behavior just like phpmyadmin.